# Delete rows from a pandas DataFrame based on a conditional expression in another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, nan

I have two pandas dataframes, df1 and df2, with both equal number of rows. df2 has 11 rows which contain NaN values. I know how to drop the empty rows in df2, by applying:

```
df2.dropna(subset=['HIGH'], inplace=True)
```

But now I want to delete these same rows from df1 (the rows with the same row numbers that have been deleted from df2). I tried the following but this does not seem to work.

```
df1.drop(df2[df2['HIGH'] == 'NaN'].index, inplace=False)
```

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Swap the two commands, drop from `df1` first, then `df2`. Or you need to cache the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all rows with NaN values in it with:

```
is_NaN = df2.isnull()
row_has_NaN = is_NaN.any(axis=1)
rows_with_NaN = df2[row_has_NaN]
```

After that you can delete the rows with NaN. (like you said in the question)

Now you can get every index out of 'rows_with_NaN'. With every index you can delete it out of df1 (Should have the same index like you said).

I hope this is correct! (No test done)